# jQuery and $ problems

Tags: jquery, format

This seems so simple but there's literally noone telling in simple english how & when it works (atleast not in first few search-engines' pages). Maybe I just suck at finding correct keywords.

I've already wrote almost 1000 lines of jQuery & I started to think that if I write more, it only brings more troble because I would probably fix it all (very very light OCD [not really but I like order] - code should be clean & "correct").

If I put my code inside `jQuery(function($) {`, it will allow me to start all stuff with `$`, else I will get "`$ is not a function`" error.

I've also noticed that some codes have `(jQuery)` in the end.

**Could someone please tell me the rules & if there's any impact if done differently?**

Comment: where are you getting this? e.g. wordpress?

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers

Comment: There's usually two reasons why `$` doesn't reference jQuery. You've either loaded jQuery in [no conflict](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/) mode, or you're attempting to use it before loading the jQuery script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This usually happens when the `jQuery` library is set to [`jQuery.noConflict()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/). An example of why this might happen is with cases such as `Wordpress` where this is done to prevent compatibility problems with other Wordpress libraries.

If you want to use `$` as an alias for the `jQuery` object as soon as the `jQuery` object is available:

```
(function($) {
    // The locally-scoped $ can be used in this function as an alias to jQuery
})(jQuery);
```

If you want to use `$` as an alias for the `jQuery` object with the [`.ready()`](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) function:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // The locally-scoped $ can be used in this function as an alias to jQuery
});
```

**Update**: Per your question in the comments, yes you can wrap `$(document).ready()` in `jQuery(function($) { })` like so:

```
jQuery(function($) {        
    $(document).ready(function() {
        alert('in .ready() using $');
    });
});
```

To make the example more comprehensive, see also what happens when jQuery frees up `$` using `.noConflict()`:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(function() {
    // $ is not locally scoped anymore, _
    // and .noConflict() is on, _
    // so the following won't work, _
    // it will return TypeError: $ is not a function
    $(document).ready(function() {
        alert('in .ready() using $');
    });
});
```

Reference material:

- [Avoiding Conflicts with Other Libraries](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/) @  jQuery Learning Centre
- [jQuery noConflict Wrappers](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers) @ Wordpress Codex

Comment: Thanks! Im wondering if `.ready` & `load` could be used inside wrapper like this: `$(document).ready(function()`? I also imagine that `jQuery(function($) {` is a prefectly valid form as main wrapper? Then you don't need `(jQuery)` at the end, right?

Comment: Uugh, still forgot one thing! Is `jQuery().something()` not causing conflicts if wrapped into jQuery? I currently don't have time to rewrite everything. Short yes or no will suffice. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It won't cause any conflicts (but there's no need to wrap `jQuery` into `jQuery`)

Comment: Just wrapping everything so that new code is as it should be from the beginning & I'll rewrite rest of the `jQuery's` and `$'s` later because some I have some codes copied from here in different formats. ;) Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

The issue you're running into seems to be rather simple: jQuery is probably used with [noConflict()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/) meaning that `$` won't be in the global namespace. To overcome this you can either remove the call to the said method or wrap your code in an anonymous function:

```
(function ($) {
    //Your code
})(jQuery);
```